# Using Virtual Box to install Ubuntu Server 14.04 on an external hard drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, external-hard-drive

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 onto a server hard drive.  The server machine I have only supports booting to CD/DVD, not USB.  When I've tried burning the Ubuntu 14.04 installer to a DVD for install, I've gotten corruption errors.  I have a SATA to USB adapter, so I want to do the initial server install from within a Virtual Box.  I've successfully created a virtual machine that [uses the external hard drive](http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/using-a-physical-hard-drive-with-a-virtualbox-vm.html) and uses the Ubuntu 14.04 iso file as the image for a virtual CD/DVD drive to install from.  I've used this setup and successfully completed the installation of the server software.  The problem is, now when I shut down the virtual machine and scan the external hard drive, it doesn't appear to have any data on it.  Using Gparted, I can't identify any partition or read any data, and I also can't boot to the external hard drive from my physical server, though it works perfectly launching from the virtual machine.  I can tell that the .vmdk that I'm using does rely on the external hard drive because the virtual machine won't launch if I unplug the USB adapter.  I'm wondering if Virtual Box is using the external hard drive, but writing data in a format that is really just another virtual hard drive.  Is there anything I can do so that I can view the server's files from outside of the virtual box itself? Thanks in advance!

Comment: So if you plug the USB install into another PC and boot into GParted Live, will the USB drive show as empty? Is it formatted at all?

Comment: @Enigma I don't have "USB install" on an actual USB drive, I simply mounted the Ubuntu server 14.04 install .iso image to the virtual box where I was installing it.  The key difference was that the virtual box's "hard drive", rather than being a .vdi file or other virtual hard drive, was directed to my server's physical drive which I had connected to my laptop via USB adapter.  After the virtual box runs the server install perfectly, I close the virtual box and check the physical drive with GParted from my laptop but it appears unformatted and I'm unable to mount it.

Comment: Maybe your ISO is corrupted. I'd try getting a DVD/CD burning working successfully as that should be much less of a headache. Burn on different computers with different drives if possible and re-download the ISO + use a hash checker to verify it's integrity.